# Maintain 2 database tables in single Dbhelper class

Tags: java, android

In my app I am trying to maintain 2 database tables, but my second table does't store values but it show successfully data was store. Here is my DbHelper class, my other java class and log cat.....

please help me.....

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sri.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "login";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ 
"username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL);";

 private static final String DB_ADMIN = "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME+"values(1, admin,        password);";

public static final String TABLE_NAME_SAVE="saveinfo";
public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
public static final String KEY_URL="surl";
public static final String KEY_UID="suid";
public static final String KEY_PASS="spassword";

public static final String SCRIPT="CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME_SAVE + "(" + "_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
"surl TEXT NOT NULL, suid TEXT NOT NULL, spassword TEXT NOT NULL);";



public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    System.out.println("In constructor");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
        //Create Database
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        //create admin account
        db.execSQL(DB_ADMIN);
        //System.out.println("In onCreate");
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }



}


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    onCreate(db);

}
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Cursor getAllValues() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String[] clumns={KEY_ID,KEY_URL,KEY_UID,KEY_PASS};
return db.query(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, clumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    void deleteAllRecords(){
  db.delete(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, null, null);
 }

 void deleteOneRecord(String rowid){
  db.delete(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, rowid +"="+KEY_ID, null);
 }

public void openDatabase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



    }
```

Here is my other java class userPageActivity.java class

```
    public class UserpageActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button save,reset,cancle,history;
EditText url,userid,password;
 DbHelper mHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private String murl,muserid,mpass;
//private boolean isUpdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userpage);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsave);
    reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.breset);
    cancle=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bcancle);
    history=(Button)findViewById(R.id.viewsi);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancle.setOnClickListener(this);
    history.setOnClickListener(this);


    url=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.urled);
    userid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userided);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passworded);

     mHelper=new DbHelper(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bsave:
    murl=url.getText().toString();
      muserid=userid.getText().toString();
      mpass=password.getText().toString();
        if(murl.length()>0 && muserid.length()>0 && password.length()>0)
        {
            saveData();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new      AlertDialog.Builder(UserpageActivity.this);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            alertBuilder.create().show();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.breset:
        url.setText("");
        userid.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        break;
    case R.id.bcancle:
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.viewsi:
        Intent ii= new   Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayActivity.class);
        startActivity(ii);
        finish();
        break;


    }
}

private void saveData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put("surl",murl);
    values.put("suid", muserid);
    values.put("spassword", mpass);

    dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME_SAVE, null, values);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Data saved...",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dataBase.close();
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserpageActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //finish();
}



}
```

Here is my logcat.......

```
03-13 02:29:42.667: E/SQLiteLog(797): (1) no such table: saveinfo
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797): Error inserting spassword=srikanth    suid=www.srikanth.com surl=srikanth
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: saveinfo (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO saveinfo(spassword,suid,surl) VALUES (?,?,?)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at com.example.personal.UserpageActivity.saveData(UserpageActivity.java:104)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at com.example.personal.UserpageActivity.onClick(UserpageActivity.java:58)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)  
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-13 02:29:42.687: E/SQLiteDatabase(797):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 02:29:42.737: I/Choreographer(797): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 02:29:44.187: I/System.out(797): In constructor
03-13 02:29:44.597: I/Choreographer(797): Skipped 416 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 02:29:47.107: I/Choreographer(797): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This logcat is shown when I ran UserPageActivity activity....and click save info button...

what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CREATE TABLE` has syntax problems:

```
public static final String SCRIPT="CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME_SAVE + "(" + "_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
    "surl TEXT NOT NULL, suid TEXT NOT NULL, spassword TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

You need space between `TABLE` and the name, like this:

```
public static final String SCRIPT="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_SAVE + "(" + "_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
    "surl TEXT NOT NULL, suid TEXT NOT NULL, spassword TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

You should not be catching exceptions in `onCreate()`. When sqlite helper `onCreate()` returns successfully, the framework thinks everything is all right and the tables got set up.

After fixing `onCreate()` as above, uninstall your app so that `onCreate()` gets called again.

Comment: hi...thanks for your replay...after replacing your answer again i got same problem.i cont understand what happen please give me some more guidence